# Agents tests OK in Dialogflow but fails when tested in Actions On Google

Tags: dialogflow-es

Agents tests great in Dialogflow but fails when tested in Actions On Google  I see this error:

```
"sharedDebugInfo": [

    {

      "name": "ResponseValidation",

      "subDebugEntry": [

        {
          "debugInfo": "API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: \": Cannot find field.\".",
          "name": "UnparseableJsonResponse"
        }
      ]
```

Note: I specify Dialogflow  API V1, not V2. Also, I am providing my own server for the webhook (not Firebase). Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The "version 2" in this case is talking about Actions on Google version 2. So don't worry about that part. Can you include the JSON that you're returning?

Comment: Actually my webhook is not being called! Works OK (i.e. webhook is called) when testing in Dialogflow.  Fails when tested in Action on Google.

Comment: Can you include screen shots of the other tabs on the simulator and the intent you think should be triggered?

Comment: same issue here. started failing a couple of days ago.
"agentToAssistantDebug": {
    "agentToAssistantJson": {
      "message": "Unexpected apiai response format: Empty speech ........
      "name": "ResponseValidation",
      "subDebugEntry": [
        {
          "debugInfo": "API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: \": Cannot find field.\".",
          "name": "UnparseableJsonResponse"
        }

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured out how to move forward. First export your Dialogflow project as a zip file. Next, create new project in Actions on Google.  Then, in Actions on Google - "Overview and Build and add actions to your app" page,  press the Build button associated with Dialogflow. On the pop up window, press "CREATE ACTIONS ON DIALOGFLOW " . Enter a new name for this Dialogflow instance, press "Save", import previously created zip file.  Works (almost) flawlessly!